# TikZ - Forest - Decorations and alignment

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I would like to add extra informations in a tree build with `forest`. I can do the following tree but the symbols are not vertically aligned... There is a similar problem with my arrows.

[image]

Here is the uggly code I use where the problem comes from the fact that I just add the symbols in the leafs of the tree...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {
        sn edges,
        grow'=0,
        l=2.5cm,
        s sep=0.2cm,
        anchor=west,
        child anchor=west}
    [
        [O
            [R
                [T $\longrightarrow$ ORT \quad $\newmoon$]
            ]
            [T
                [R $\longrightarrow$ OTR \quad $\newmoon$]
            ]
        ]
        [R
            [O
                [T $\longrightarrow$ ROT \quad $\blacksquare$ \quad $\blacktriangle$]
            ]
            [T
                [O $\longrightarrow$ RTO \quad $\blacktriangle$]
            ]
        ]
        [T
            [O
                [R $\longrightarrow$ TOR]
            ]
            [R
                [O $\longrightarrow$ TRO]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

How to add my decorations such that they become aligned vertically ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would integrate the arrows into the tree, also, but since all and only terminus nodes get arrows, I would add them programmatically.

Originally, I suggested adding the symbols using Forest's `label` option. For convenience, I used a style `symb` for this which also wrapped its value in `$ ... $` to save repeating them in every case.

However, this causes misalignment because the nodes in the final level are not of equal width. If the nodes are very similar in size and are predictable, you could just set `text width=<some dimension>` for these along with `edge=->`. However, a more elegant solution is to add the symbols themselves into separate nodes.

If we create a new Forest option `symb`, we can then add this into a node after the tree is parsed, but before the nodes are typeset. I've used `anchor=parent` but you could obviously use something else, if preferred. The advantage of this is partly that custom Forest options are a neat trick, but mostly that it is more flexible than `label` and, unlike `label`s, Forest will keep track of these nodes and the space they require in the usual way.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym,amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={symb}{},
  symb tree/.style={%
    for tree = {%
      sn edges,
      grow'=0,
      l=2.5cm,
      s sep=0.2cm,
      anchor=parent,
      if n children=0{%
        edge=->,
      }{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where n children=0{%
        append/.wrap pgfmath arg={[$##1$, no edge, grow'=0, anchor=parent, l=0em]}{symb()},
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  symb tree,
  [
    [O
      [R
        [T [ORT, symb=\newmoon]
        ]
      ]
      [T
        [R [OTR, symb=\newmoon]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [R
      [O
        [T [ROT, symb=\blacksquare \quad \blacktriangle]
        ]
      ]
      [T
        [O [RTO, symb=\blacktriangle]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [T
      [O
        [R [TOR]
        ]
      ]
      [R
        [O [TRO]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree with symbolic annotations]

## EDIT

In [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329451/tikz-forest-drawing-upon-a-subtree), you asked about encircling groups of nodes. I thought it might be helpful to demonstrate some options for extending the example above to do this.

The code below shades behind the node groups as well as circling them, using the `backgrounds` library.

We amend the contents of `\forestset{}` as follows.

We first add a couple of other custom options. One is a boolean (on or off - defaults to off). We use this to track where the symbols are. The other tracks a colour for circling nodes, red by default.

```
  declare boolean={symb here}{0},
  declare toks={circle colour}{red},
```

Then we amend the `symb tree` style slightly. We change the code in `before typesetting nodes` to add a `symb here` marker to the nodes containing the symbols.

```
          append/.wrap pgfmath arg={[$##1$, no edge, grow'=0, anchor=parent, l=0em, symb here]}{symb()},
```

We also define a custom nodewalk step which picks out the nodes with the `symb here` marker. This will let us encircle all and only the symbol nodes, should we wish to do so.

```
  define long step={symb tree symbs}{}{fake=root, filter={tree}{symb_here} },
```

Now for a style to circle the symbols. It takes one optional argument for the colour.

```
  circle symbols/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      !r.tikz+={%
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [circle me, #1, fit to=symb tree symbs] {};}
      },
    },
  },
```

Here's one for encircling the subtree of the current node, again with an optional colour argument.

```
  circle subtree/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      tikz+={%
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [circle me, #1, fit to=tree] {};}
      },
    },
  },
```

Now we want a generic `circle fit to` style for encircling other stuff. This *needs* an argument: the stuff to be encircled. So the colour can't be set as an argument here. However, we can still change the colour using `circle colour=<colour>`, if we don't want the default.

```
  circle fit to/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      tikz+={%
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [circle me, fit to={#1}] {};}
      },
    },
  },
```

This is a Ti*k*Z style for the circling nodes. It uses the `circle colour` to draw and fill, but the filling is only 10% opaque.

```
  /tikz/circle me/.style={%
    draw=\forestoption{circle colour}, fill=\forestoption{circle colour}, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners, thick, fill opacity=.10, draw opacity=1,
  },
```

Now, we can use these styles and options to decorate our tree from above.

```
\begin{forest}
  symb tree,
```

We want to encircle all the symbols using `blue`.

```
  circle symbols=blue,
  [
```

We'd like all of `O`'s descendants to be circled in `magenta`.

```
    [O, circle fit to=descendants, circle colour=magenta
      [R
        [T [ORT, symb=\newmoon]
        ]
      ]
      [T
        [R [OTR, symb=\newmoon]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

We'd like all the nodes in `R`'s subtree which are three levels below `R` to be circled in the default colour.

```
    [R, circle fit to={relative level=3}
      [O
```

We'd like `T`, `T`'s grand-parent and the grand-parent's second child to be highlighted in `blue!50!cyan`. Obviously, this will also capture `T`'s parent and the child of the second child, just because of the shape of a rectangular node.

```
        [T, circle fit to={c,uu,2}, circle colour=blue!50!cyan [ROT, symb=\blacksquare \quad \blacktriangle]
        ]
      ]
      [T
        [O [RTO, symb=\blacktriangle]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

`T`'s subtree should be highlighted in `green!75!black`.

```
    [T, circle subtree=green!75!black,
      [O
        [R [TOR]
        ]
      ]
      [R
        [O [TRO]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Our tree then looks as follows.

[image: decorated tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym,amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\forestset{%
  declare toks={symb}{},
  declare boolean={symb here}{0},
  declare toks={circle colour}{red},
  symb tree/.style={%
    for tree = {%
      sn edges,
      grow'=0,
      l=2.5cm,
      s sep=0.2cm,
      anchor=parent,
      if n children=0{%
        edge=->,
      }{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where n children=0{%
        if symb={}{}{%
          append/.wrap pgfmath arg={[$##1$, no edge, grow'=0, anchor=parent, l=0em, symb here]}{symb()},
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
  define long step={symb tree symbs}{}{fake=root, filter={tree}{symb_here} },
  circle symbols/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      !r.tikz+={%
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [circle me, #1, fit to=symb tree symbs] {};}
      },
    },
  },
  circle subtree/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      tikz+={%
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [circle me, #1, fit to=tree] {};}
      },
    },
  },
  circle fit to/.style={%
    before drawing tree={%
      tikz+={%
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [circle me, fit to={#1}] {};}
      },
    },
  },
  /tikz/circle me/.style={%
    draw=\forestoption{circle colour}, fill=\forestoption{circle colour}, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners, thick, fill opacity=.10, draw opacity=1,
  },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  symb tree,
  circle symbols=blue,
  [
    [O, circle fit to=descendants, circle colour=magenta
      [R
        [T [ORT, symb=\newmoon]
        ]
      ]
      [T
        [R [OTR, symb=\newmoon]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [R, circle fit to={relative level=3}
      [O
        [T, circle fit to={c,uu,2}, circle colour=blue!50!cyan [ROT, symb=\blacksquare \quad \blacktriangle]
        ]
      ]
      [T
        [O [RTO, symb=\blacktriangle]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [T, circle subtree=green!75!black,
      [O
        [R [TOR]
        ]
      ]
      [R
        [O [TRO]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that there is a alignment problem with the filled discus.

Comment: Thalles for the update of your answer.

Comment: @projetmbc Please see edit above.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a variant where the arrows are drawn by the forest package. The additional symbols are added by using tikz directly to draw extra nodes in a distance of `1cm` (or whatever the optional parameter says).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym,amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\symb[2][1cm]{\draw () ++(#1,0) node{#2};}
\begin{forest}
    for tree = {sn edges, grow'=0, l=2.5cm, s sep=0.2cm, anchor=west, child anchor=west}
    [ [O [R [T [ORT,edge=->] {\symb{$\newmoon$}}]]
         [T [R [OTR,edge=->] {\symb{$\newmoon$}}]]
      ]
      [R [O [T [ROT,edge=->] {\symb{$\blacksquare$}\symb[2cm]{$\blacktriangle$}}]]
         [T [O [RTO,edge=->] {\symb{$\blacktriangle$}}]]
      ]
      [T [O [R [TOR,edge=->]]]
         [R [O [TRO,edge=->]]]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for `draw` and `node`. This does the job. For the arrows, the use of `edge=->` produces arrows too long. So I have decided to use another `draw` and `node` pattern.

Comment: I've cleaned up a bit here. You may like to do the same?