# TikZ forest - Drawing upon a subtree

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I would like to add a rectangle upon a subtree like in the following picture. How to do that ?

[image]

Here is the `forest` code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {
        sn edges,
        grow'=0,
        l=2.5cm,
        s sep=0.2cm,
        anchor=west,
        child anchor=west}
  [
    [O
      [R
        [T]
      ]
      [T
        [R]
      ]
    ]
    [R
      [O
        [T]
      ]
      [T
        [O]
      ]
    ]
    [T
      [O
        [R]
      ]
      [R
        [O]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign names to nodes in `forest`, so you can use this together with the Tikz `fit` library to draw a node around the nodes you have chosen.

If you don't want to use a node, you can also just do (doesn't require any library):

```
\draw[red,thick] (bottomright.south east) rectangle (left.west|-topright.north);
```

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree = {
        sn edges,
        grow'=0,
        l=2.5cm,
        s sep=0.2cm,
        anchor=west,
        child anchor=west}
  [
    [O,name=left
      [R
        [T,name=topright]
      ]
      [T
        [R,name=bottomright]
      ]
    ]
    [R
      [O
        [T]
      ]
      [T
        [O]
      ]
    ]
    [T
      [O
        [R]
      ]
      [R
        [O]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\node[draw=red,thick,fit=(left)(topright)(bottomright)] {};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great and easy to use ! Thanks for this.

Comment: @projetmbc I added an alternative, see edit. :)

Comment: Another great feature ! I really like that "everything" is automated.

Comment: If the aim is to enclose all children of a node, you can also apply `tikz={\node [draw,red,fit to=tree] {};}` directly to that node.

Comment: So cute !  Is there a shorter way ? With my question I'm kiding. 

Comment: @projetmbc Or `, tikz+={\node [draw=red, fit=() (!u) (!uu)] {};}` to circle the node, the node's parent and the node's grandparent, for example.

Comment: @cfr I can achieve to use `tikz+={\node [draw=red, fit=() (!u) (!uu)] {};}` contrary to `tikz={\node [draw,red,fit to=tree] {};}`. Can you update your example to show how to use the circle version.

Comment: Alenanno ^^^^ @projetmbc It isn't my answer :-).

Comment: @cfr Does he want `tikz={\node [draw,red,fit to=tree] {};}`?

Comment: Alenanno I thought it was a request for `tikz+={\node [draw=red, fit=() (!u) (!uu)] {};}` but I'm not sure. Maybe it means that works (`can achieve`) but the other doesn't seem to work and the question is how to make it work. @projetmbc Could you clarify? It also occurred to me that you might be asking how to combine one of these things with my answer to your other question. If you let us know what you're trying to do, one or other of us can update accordingly ;).

Comment: How can I write some text outside of the node / box? Any text inside the `{}` will print it in the box.

Comment: @LukasCB Use labels, like `label={above:<test>}` in the node options.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329449/ [already pinged @projetmbc ...]

Comment: @cfr I can't achieve to grow a rounded rectangle. What is the easiest way to do that ?

Comment: @projetmbc What do you mean? Just `rounded corners`?

Comment: So simple... Sorry for my question.